# Count multiple occurrence of all string elements in a list?

Tags: python-3.x

How can I get a count of all the string elements from the given list?

```
Var1 = ['2019-11-22', '2019-11-22', '2019-11-20']
```

Desired Output:

```
2019-11-22 : count(2)
2019-11-20 : count(1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

var1 = ['2019-11-22', '2019-11-22', '2019-11-20']

for i, c in Counter(var1).items():
   print(f"{i}: count({c})")
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot for the update

Answer (score 4):

That's what a counter is for.

```py
from collections import Counter

Var1 = ['2019-11-22', '2019-11-22', '2019-11-20']
counts = Counter(Var1)
```